# Nodejs POST request not working; no real error code shown

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

So, I'm having an issue communicating with an API using nodejs. I've tried everything and a half, from using different request modules from the one supplied to changing the format and everything else and a half.

The code is here...

```
var request = require("request"); 
var prompt = require('prompt');
var $ = require('jquery');
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

var y = [];
var z = [];
var ids = [];

var x = "";
var pTL = "";
var vTL = "";
var url = "";

function requestN(name){
  //does things regarding name.
  url = https://example.com/ //Not actual domain. Is example.
  request(url, function (error, response, body) { //Grabs data from server
     if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      x = body;
    }
    if (error || response.statusCode != 200 ){
      console.log('Network Error ' + response.statusCode + '. Program will exit shortly...');
    }
    prepareInput();
  });
}

function format(){

//There is a whole lot of things here that regard parsing strings and things like that. This isn't the issue; I checked.

for( var d1 = 0; d1 < ids.length; d1++){
if( d1 + 1 != false){ //Checks if undefined.
  var obj = { 
    "_label": "LABEL",
    "_inV": ids[d1],
    "_outV": ids[d1 + 1]
  }
  sendTo(obj);
}
  }
};

function sendTo(obj){
  jsdom.env("", ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"], function(err, window) {
      var $ = window.$
      $.support.cors = true;
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: 'POST',
        error: function(e) {
          console.log(e.status); //Always returns a code of '0', for some reason.
          console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) //debug
        },
        success: function(objString){ //Success never triggers, for some reason.
          console.log('Potato'); //debug
          console.log(objString);
        }
      });
  });

/* This was also tried; The API kept throwing error 500 at me.
var mOptions = {
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST"
  }
  request.post(mOptions, function(error, response, body){
      console.log(response);
  });
*/
}

prompt.start(); //Asks for your input
console.log('Please enter property and value to link, and the page to link it to.');
prompt.get(['name', 'property', 'val'], function(err, result){
  pTL = result.property;
  vTL = result.val;
  var name = result.name;
  requestN(name);
});
```

I'm at my wits end. Two different people have no idea what's going on here, and the API works perfectly on another computer(uses the exact same Ajax request format, too.)
e returns this:

```
{ readyState: 0,
  getResponseHeader: [Function],
  getAllResponseHeaders: [Function],
  setRequestHeader: [Function],
  overrideMimeType: [Function],
  statusCode: [Function],
  abort: [Function],
  state: [Function],
  always: [Function],
  then: [Function],
  promise: [Function],
  pipe: [Function],
  done: [Function],
  fail: [Function],
  progress: [Function],
  complete: [Function],
  success: [Function],
  error: [Function],
  responseText: '',
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'error' }
```

Node Version v4.2.6

Comment: can you share the server side code? Also are you trying to make a post request wirth your first request example, didn't see type set to post nor the body included. Also your function is overwriting the request namespace is that intended?

Comment: I cannot, sorry. Also, yes, I am. See the 'type: 'POST'.

Comment: I meant this one: function request(name){...}

Comment: That's not a POST request; that's a GET request. It's getting something from the API, making it into something else, then spitting it back out at the API.

Comment: cool just making sure, why not use it for the post request (just curious why jquery was needed here)

Comment: Because it's not working, for some reason. When I try to use the request.post method, I get an error 500 from the server. When I try to use the jquery method, I get a statusCode of 0 from the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113174/discussion-between-mark-essel-and-orlando-marinella).

Comment: What is `requestGraph` (undefined)? Why do you redefine `var request =.. ` with `function request` and why does request call it self in an infinite recursive loop?

Comment: requestGraph was supposed to be request. That was rectified.  And it doesn't seem to call itself infinitely, actually. It terminates after one iteration.

Comment: "It terminates after one iteration" -- no i does not terminate itself *ever*, it calls itself unconditionally in the second line of code of the function.

Comment: That's part of the npm request module. See npm.com/packages/request. (It's named something else in the actual file, I just scrubbed the names here to protect some information. Sorry about that.)

Comment: You have obvious name conflict between `var request` and `function request`. Rename one of them to continue.

Comment: @vp_arth: Yes, yes. Sorry about that, again, see my last comment, however. It's named something different in the actual code, but I will rename it here to avoid confusion.

Comment: Keeping on editing the question that way will not get you any *real* help here, even with a bounty.  It is clear that the code you have above is not representative of what you are really trying to do.  You need to reduce your code to a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- something which **actually runs** on it own and demonstrate the problem you are having, including the input and the output you are getting and expecting

Comment: `This question has opened bounty and cannot be closed` But it should be closed, it's just a bunch of broken `client` code with question `why my server doesn't work?` It's unclear at all what answer expected here.

Comment: I see. The main purpose of asking this question was just to see if I was doing anything wrong here, that is, if I somehow borked the request, or I've mismanaged the virtual window that runs that Ajax, etc. etc. I was full well prepared to see it was the server tripping up, but it's always nice the check the easily editable bit first.

Comment: @vp_arth: This isn't an issue with the server. See most recent answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay.

So, this wasn't a server issue. I've figured it out, and it's slightly obscure. Note: This is applicable to other nodejs servers using the npm request module to send a json object.

```
var mOptions = {
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST"
  }
  request.post(mOptions, function(error, response, body){
      console.log(response);
  });
```

This code above, doesn't work. However, with a little correction,

```
var mOptions = {
    url: url,
    json: obj,
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST"
  }
  request.post(mOptions, function(error, response, body){
      console.log(response);
  });
```

It does. I'm unsure why this makes such a large of a difference, whether it's a server thing or the module's thing, but this is what does it. Ta-da. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score -1):

try to format your data as json by using the **dataType** field.

Here's an example of what I'm using to get a (OAUTH2) Token:

```
function doRequestDataWithUserPass(){
    var userId="a@b.com"; 
    var pass="aaa"; 
    var formUserPass = { client_id: clientId, 
    client_secret: clientSecret, 
    username: userId, 
    password: pass, 
    scope: 'read_station', 
    grant_type: 'password' };
    $.ajax({
     async: false,
    url: "https://example.net/oauth2/token",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: formUserPass,
      success: onSuccess
    });
}

function onSuccess(data){
// debug
}
```